# How to call awk to process /var/log/wtmp?

Tags: bash, awk

This is my list file

```
neifer   pts/1        161.10.120.51    Tue Oct 23 01:08 - 01:13  (00:04)
neifer   pts/1        161.10.120.51    Tue Oct 23 00:47 - 01:08  (00:20)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-042stab11 Mon Oct 22 15:34 - 01:43  (10:08)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-042stab11 Mon Oct 22 12:45 - 15:33  (02:48)
root     pts/0        125.160.194.15   Mon Oct 22 04:45 - 04:46  (00:01)
root     pts/0        125.160.194.15   Sat Oct 20 02:06 - 02:13  (00:06)
```

I want to keep only some parts, namely:

```
root     pts/0        125.160.194.15
root     pts/0        125.160.194.15
```

I tried this command but it did not work:

```
awk '/root/ { print $1, $2, $3 }' /var/log/wtmp
```

Comment: I assume the mention of the filename is an honest mistake? =}  This looks like the output of `last`, `wtmp` is a binary file ...

Comment: ok thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway - this does (I think) what you want. Rather than attempting to process the binary file directly with awk try the following:

```
 last | awk '/root/{printf "%-8s\t%-6s\t%s\n", $1, $2, $3}'
```

Comment: i find with this command : `last -f /var/log/wtmp | awk '/root/ {print $1, $2, $3 }'`

Comment: Could also set OFS to tab.